# POST with no value returned in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I have a button on my client site that send a POST request to my server. In this request, I have no need to return anything as it just makes an insert in my database. However after the click on the button, my client keeps waiting for an answer until it fails. But I don't want to return anything as I don't want the page to be refreshed. How to manage it ?

FYI my server is in nodejs, my client in EJS / html / common js, my database is mongoDb. If possible I prefer to keep only these technology.

[Edit] What I want to perform is a tracking service. Each time a user clicks on a button, a data is inserted in the database. On its side, the button only launches the play of a music.

Thanks.

Extract of my client code :

```
<form style="display:inline;" action="/genre" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="genre" value='<%= musicFile.genre %>' />
 <input onclick="play('audioPlayer', '<%= musicFile.path %>')"" type="submit" value="Play" />
</form>
```

Extract of my server code :

```
router.post('/genre', function(req, res)
{
    var genre = req.body.genre;
    console.log('POST genre')
    console.log(genre)
    if (!genre) return;
    Genre.findOne({'genre' : genre}, 'number', function(err, res)
    {
        var nb = 1;
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        if (res)    nb = res.number + 1;
        Genre.update({'genre' : genre}, {'number' : nb}, {upsert : true}, function(err, res)
        {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log('Updated genres collection - Genre ' + genre + ' listened ' + nb + 'times');
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Either submit the form via ajax/hidden iframe or make a redirect in response to the POST. You can't just not respond to the HTTP request.

Comment: what do you mean by "submit the form via ajax/hidden iframe" ? how to do that ? what will it change ? or is there a way to make redirect but to avoid the refresh of the page ?

Comment: Why do want to ignore the response in the first place? What if an error occurs?

Comment: actually my only purpose is to avoid the refresh of my page. I thought the only way not to send any response but I might be wrong. But you're right. So what would be the proper way to perform it ?

Answer (score 0):

You must always return status. Your client is waiting to see if the POST was successful or if it failed. You don't have to return any data.

If the POST is successful, you should return a 200.

```
 Genre.update({'genre' : genre}, {'number' : nb}, {upsert : true}, function(err, res)

 if (err) return handleError(err);
 res.status(200).send() // I'm not sure you will need the .send()
```

Comment: tried but not ok. I need the .send() so my page is refreshed with what I sent (even if I pass no argument)

Answer (score 0):

You need `error.html`, `success_page.html` files to render (as per example), after form is submitted, expressJS handles all db queries, and renders a file as a result. Also your incrementation is quite heavy, use built-in `$inc` operator instead, so in the end you have only 1 request to Database

```
//submitted from submit-form.html
router.post('/genre', function(req, res) {
    var genre = req.body.genre;
    if (!genre) {
        //render error.html (or .ejs file)
        return res.render('error', {message: 'No gender selected'});
    } else {
        //update gender with $inc operator
        Genre.update({'genre': genre}, {$inc: {number: 1}}, function(updateError, updateResult) {
            if (updateError) {
                res.render('error', err);
            } else {
                //render success_page.html (or .ejs file)
                //res.render('success_page');
                //or render current form submit-form.html instead
                res.render('submit-form', {genderUpdated: true}); //use genderUpdated for custom behavior
            }
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. So how to perform what I want to, which is : make an insert in my database without moving to another page ?

Comment: Updated, basically if you submit from `form-1.ejs` then just render itself again, `res.render('form-1', {genderUpdated: true});`

Comment: But it will refresh the whole page, right ? If so, that's not what I want. Actually a click on the button launches the play of a music. So a render will cut this play.

Comment: Yes, it will re-render page, because you are using default FORM tag, it's document oriented, and quite old tag, in your case you should use Ajax request in the background, FORM tag will not work as you expect. There are plenty of libraries for Ajax requests, like $.ajax, request.js, etc. I would suggest you to open a new question as this is totally incorrect description you provided

Comment: Hi actually I managed to do it by using XMLHttpRequest (exemple found there : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript). Works perfectly ! thanks again !